# Python - Calculate the average of values starting after a condition (e.g., after first non-zero in another column)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below that details a count for each product over a fixed date range. For some products, which were introduced later than the starting of the date range, I would like to calculate the average of the count variable only after that date.

For example below, "rice" doesn't appear until Oct 3 so the average would only be the for the values on Oct 3 and 4 for rice, but for "beans" the average would be for Oct 1-4.

The groupby code I am using calculates the mean for each product overall 4 days.

How can control the mean calculation to be over the dates starting after the first non-zero value of count?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-10-01', 'beans', 10],
                   ['2019-10-02', 'beans', 4],
                   ['2019-10-03', 'beans', 5],
                   ['2019-10-04', 'beans', 7],
                   ['2019-10-01', 'rice', 0],
                   ['2019-10-02', 'rice', 0],
                   ['2019-10-03', 'rice', 3],
                   ['2019-10-04', 'rice', 2]],
                  columns=['dt', 'product', 'count'])
df.groupby("product")['count'].describe()['mean']
```

So the mean for 'rice' would ebe 2.5 in this case.

If I had a 9th row `['2019-10-05', 'rice', 0]`, then this zero-count row would be included in the mean for 'rice' which would then be 1.6666.

Comment: So, to be perfectly clear: if you have a 9th row `['2019-10-05', 'rice', 0]`, then this zero-count row *would* be included in the mean for `'rice'` which would then be 1.6666? Is that correct?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes, you are correct. That zero-count row would be included for the mean calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df["valid"]=df.groupby("product")["count"].cumsum().ne(0)
df.loc[df.valid].groupby("product")["count"].mean()
```

Alternatively, in case, if you can have negative `count`:

```py
df["valid"]=df["count"].ne(0).groupby(df["product"]).cumsum().ne(0)
df.loc[df.valid].groupby("product")["count"].mean()
```

Output:

```py
product
beans    6.5
rice     2.5
Name: count, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this works. You calculate the cumulative sum at each row for each product. Then you flag the rows with a cumulative sum greater than 0 so you can calculate the mean for only the flagged rows.

Comment: Correct, in case if ```count``` would get negative- it's a bit more overhead cause you do the same - but with Boolean ```count>0```

Comment: Can you comment a bit on what .ne is doing? I tried Googling a bit on it but without success and changing the 0 argument to 9 resulting in unexpected flags.

Comment: @DPatel: This answer seems to be fitting your needs well. I would suggest accepting this answer.

Comment: Yup so in essence- ```df["count"].ne(0)``` is equivalent to ```(df["count"]!=0)```.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want:

```
m = df.groupby('product')['count'].transform('mean')
df['mean'] = df['count'].mask(df['count'].ne(0)).fillna(m)
```

```
           dt product  count  mean
0  2019-10-01   beans     10  6.50
1  2019-10-02   beans      4  6.50
2  2019-10-03   beans      5  6.50
3  2019-10-04   beans      7  6.50
4  2019-10-01    rice      0  0.00
5  2019-10-02    rice      0  0.00
6  2019-10-03    rice      3  1.25
7  2019-10-04    rice      2  1.25
```